# Why wrong spelling in str.length doesn't show an error in JS

Tags: javascript, console, string-length, misspelling

I'm a beginner javascript dev, I wrote this code:

```
var foo = "sunny";
var longitudInt = foo.length;
console.log("The length of " + foo + " is " + longitudInt);
```

But when I wrote foo.length, I made a spelling mistake and wrote foo.lenght, but it didn't show an error in the console, Why?
[It doesn't show an error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7Guy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`foo.lenght` will not raise an error but it will return `undefined`. The reason for this is that `foo` is a `String` type variable and when it try to call the property `lenght` (which is invalid), it does not get that in its prototype. Thus, it returns with `undefined` instead of error.

```js
var foo = 'str';
console.log(foo.lenght);
```

However, if you try to access other properties in `foo.lenght` say, `foo.lenght.len` then this will give you error because at this time `foo.lenght` is `undefined` and it tries to read a property of a `undefined` type.

```js
var foo = 'str';
console.log(foo.lenght.len);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value of "something".lenght (or anything really, "something".foobar) will be "[undefined](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined)" (roughly equivalent to null).

It doesn't throw an exception as it would with some other languages